# Is Firefox not rendering a web page correctly compared to the same version on Windows?

Tags: 11.10, firefox, windows, chromium

I recently discovered that Firefox on Ubuntu does not render well some web pages compared to how it renders them on Windows (where the rendering is correct) or even to Chromium on the same Ubuntu box (Chromium also renders them correctly).

I thought it was a problem with Ubuntu, but using Chromium on Ubuntu convinced me that it may be a problem in Firefox or a combination of Firefox and Ubuntu.

Here is a screenshot of an area of a webpage rendered with Firefox:

[image]

And here is another one for the same area but rendered correctly with Chromium under the same Ubuntu machine:

[image]

I'm using the latest stable Firefox version: 7.0.1 on the latest 11.10 Ubuntu release.

I tried to remove (totally) and reinstall Firefox but the problem persists. I never experienced this problem with previous Firefox releases on previous Ubuntu systems for the same webpages.

The screen shots where taken from http://www.builtwith.com.

Any insights?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is not incorrect rendering at all. The difference here is simply themeing. What you are seeing is the difference between button styles. On Chrome (and on Windows) the buttons are slightly smaller which causes them to line up with the box.

On Firefox (in Ubuntu) the button is rendered using the GTK+ style.

Comment: I'm aware of that, but as I stated I never experienced those problems before with previous Firefox versions on Windows or on Ubuntu. This is really weird!

Comment: @Wassim: ಠ_ಠ... no it isn't!

Comment: Ok maybe you're right, but explain me why I didn't notice this problem in previous versions of Firefox on Ubuntu?

Comment: @Wassim It's theming. Chrome/chromeium, Firefox and opera all theme things differently. As for why you didn't notice it, perhaps you weren't looking?  Having use Ubuntu since 10.04, I can assure you that the theme hasn't changed (much).

Comment: @jrg: I'm sure I looked in the same area of the screenshot for the past 3 years (I use it alot), and of course I was using Firefox/Ubuntu, and it rendered well.

Comment: @Wassim if it really isn't rendering correctly (which I doubt), then this should be reported as a bug! [Instructions here](http://askubuntu.com/questions/5121/how-do-i-report-a-bug).

Comment: @Wassim the theme in 11.10 changed (the entire GTK+ engine underneath changed!) significantly enough that you should notice this. It's really nothing.

Comment: @RolandTaylor: Ok, I think I'm buying your answer. Thanks.